# Excel VBA UserForm - Minimise Button

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, userform

**Hi All,**

I have been working on a couple user forms within Excel VBA for a few days now along with assistance from another gentleman on an issue. Whilst working on them I realised it's a nightmare as I can't click off of them onto my spreadsheet, which is what has lead me to ask the question; **Is there a way to create a minimize button next to the close icon at the top right of the userform?** I would prefer this to just a random button, but if either is possible, would anyone be able to assist. I have already attempted it `.hide`, but that doesn't appear to work.

If it helps, I am using **Excel 2010**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hey @Doug, for your info, you can achieve this using Windows API (which is what the answer below is). Just keep in mind with UserForms that they don't appear on the TaskBar as an icon (unless you tell it to in your code) so your userform can easily get lost if you minimize it or when running as `vbModeless` (which doesn't lock you to the userform) it's easy to lose behind your other windows. There are heaps of other SO questions with answers and examples of using Windows API with VBA (much like the answer below) which you might find useful if you need further functionality of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```html
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
InitMaxMin Me.Caption
End Sub
```

Put This code in module

```html
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function FindWindowA& Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName$, ByVal lpWindowName$)
Public Declare Function GetWindowLongA& Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd&, ByVal nIndex&)
Public Declare Function SetWindowLongA& Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd&, ByVal nIndex&, ByVal dwNewLong&)
' Déclaration des constantes
Public Const GWL_STYLE As Long = -16
Public Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX = &H20000
Public Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = &H10000
Public Const WS_FULLSIZING = &H70000
'Attention, envoyer après changement du caption de l'UF
Public Sub InitMaxMin(mCaption As String, Optional Max As Boolean = True, Optional Min As Boolean = True _
        , Optional Sizing As Boolean = True)
Dim hwnd As Long
    hwnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, mCaption)
    If Min Then SetWindowLongA hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    If Max Then SetWindowLongA hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    If Sizing Then SetWindowLongA hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_FULLSIZING
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, But it still won't allow me to use the spread sheet whilst it is minimised.

Comment: Ok,to show userform you can use UserForm1.Show vbModeless